# Avoiding color blindness penalty programmatically

Tags: javascript, html, colors, accessibility

I learned as a web developer that if the color contrast on a website is terrible, then I make very little money but I want to change that, however I ran into a problem. I have a section on my site where a user can select a color and the box is filled with that color. Let's say the color is already chosen. The box will then be like this in code for a black box:

```
<div ID="box" style="background:#000000;width:16px;height:16px">Text?</div>
```

The thing is the `#000000` will change to another value based on the user's selection from running javascript. I feel that to make all CSS processors including google happy, I need to specify a foreground color so that its readable on any background color but I don't know the math behind this.

```
<script>
var x=(insert chosen color value);
var y=(some calculated value);
document.getElementById('box').style.background='#'+v;
document.getElementById('box').style.color='#'+y;
</script>
```

How do I determine the formula for foreground color regardless of the background color I choose to use so that the text is always readable?

OR

should I use a different HTML4 element to represent my color box?

and could I get away with this without having to make an image of just color boxes?

**More added code**

Run this code to get a sample of the strip of colours I use for my colour box.

```
<div ID="BOX" style="width:100%"></div>
<script>
var body=document.getElementById('BOX');
for (n=0;n<15;n++){
  var box=document.createElement('DIV');
  box.style.width='20px';
  box.style.height='20px';
  v=n.toString(16);
  box.style.background='#'+v+v+v+v+v+v;
  body.appendChild(box);
}
</script>
```

Comment: The simple way is, calculate the brightness of the background color (using the standard RGB to brightness formula) and then use white for the foreground color if the background is dark, black otherwise. That way, you'll have best contrast and best readability.

Comment: This opposite color will always stick out. IE black and white: `background:#000000, foreground:#FFFFFF` red and cyan: `background:#FF0000, foreground:#00FFFF`

Comment: @TonyRuth Cyan on a red background is not perfectly readable on all monitors. Play it safe and use white for a foreground.

Comment: but I'm using a color palette in as many color ranges as possible including black, white, and grey, and all shades of the rainbow colours.

Comment: and Mr. Lister, If I used your formula, then how would grey work? the contrast would be terrible.... grey on grey?

Comment: @Mike if you use my formula and you get grey on grey, you're doing it wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is my old function for check and create a color contrast (I use this in a color picker).

This is the line you can change for test the function:

```
var hexcolor = '#333333'; // <--- change this for test
```

**[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/vu0a5wkc/)**

HTML:

```
<div id="bckgrd" >
  <div id="txt">
    TEST CODE
  </div>
</div>
```

THE CSS:

```
html, body {
  background-color:#ff0000;
}
#bckgrd {
  display:inline-block;
  width:100%;
  font-size:18px;
}
```

THE JAVASCRIPT:

```
function colorContrast(color) {
    var r = hexToRgb(color).r;
  var g = hexToRgb(color).g;
  var b = hexToRgb(color).b;
  var rB = 255, gB = 255, bB = 255;
  var rN = 0, gN = 0, bN = 0;

  var cB = Math.abs(r - rB) + Math.abs(g - gB) + Math.abs(b - bB);
  var br1 = (299*r + 587*g + 114*b);
  var br2 = (299*rB + 587*gB + 114*bB);
  var dB = Math.abs(br1 - br2);

  var cN = Math.abs(r - rN) + Math.abs(g - gN) + Math.abs(b - bN);
  br2 = (299*rN + 587*gN + 114*bN);
  var dN = Math.abs(br1 - br2);

  if ((cB>500) && (dB>125)){
    return '#ffffff';
  } else if ((cN>500) && (dN>125)){
    return '#000000';
  } else {
    if ( ((0.2*cB) + (0.8*dB)) > ((0.2*cN) + (0.8*dN)) ) {
      return '#FFFFFF';
    } else {
      return '#000000';
    }
  }


}

function hexToRgb(hex) {

    var shorthandRegex = /^#?([a-f\d])([a-f\d])([a-f\d])$/i;
    hex = hex.replace(shorthandRegex, function(m, r, g, b) {
        return r + r + g + g + b + b;
    });

    var result = /^#?([a-f\d]{2})([a-f\d]{2})([a-f\d]{2})$/i.exec(hex);
    return result ? {
        r: parseInt(result[1], 16),
        g: parseInt(result[2], 16),
        b: parseInt(result[3], 16)
    } : null;
}
var hexcolor = '#333333'; // <--- change this for test
$('#txt').css('color', hexcolor);
$('#bckgrd').css('background-color', colorContrast(hexcolor));
```

Comment: I'm trying to understand how the numbers 0.2 and 0.8 were chosen in `((0.2*cB) + (0.8*dB)) > ((0.2*cN) + (0.8*dN))`

Comment: It 's been a long time, but the function I built with an explanation like this: http://www.had2know.com/technology/color-contrast-calculator-web-design.html.
If I remember correctly, that calculation gave results in which the contrast and brightness was not enough in it on white on black. My goal was just to have a contrast of only these two colors, and after several manual tests, I arrived at that result, which seemed sufficiently correct.